# Blank page when rendering a partial with ajax in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a nav menu with 2 tabs/links in the `show.html.erb` file, in `UsersController.rb`, I would like to use ajax to render different partial for the tabs.

In the `show.html.erb` I have a div named `profile-data` where I want to show the content.
So I do something like this:

**The link structure:**

```
<li><%= link_to "College friends", college_friends_path, :remote => true %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Highschool friends", highschool_friends_path, :remote => true %></li>
```

**I define the routes:**

```
match "college_friends" => "users#college_friends", :as => "college_friends"
match "highschool_friends" => "users#highschool_friends, :as => "highschool_friends"
```

**And I define in my UserController.rb the necessary methods:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def college_friends
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def highschool_friends
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**Last thing we have the JS files:**

*college_friends.js.erb*

```
$('#profile-data').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'college_friends')) %>");
```

*highschool_friends.js.erb*

```
$('#profile-data').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'highschool_friends')) %>");
```

**The partial code: _college_friends.html.erb**

```
<% groups = @user.friends.group_by(&:college_name) %>
<% sorted_groups = groups.sort_by{|key, values| values.count}.reverse %>
<% sorted_groups.each do |collegename, friends| %>
<% next if collegename.blank? %>
<div class="contentbox">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3><%= collegename %></h3>
        <div class="meta-info">
            <p><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> Malmö</p>
            <p><i class="icon-user"></i><span class="count"> <%= friends.count %></span> vänner</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="friends-list">
        <% friends.map do |friend| %>
        <li><%= image_tag(friend.image) %>
            <% end %> 
        </ul> 
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**So I solve this problem but checking the source in and out. And I notice that the js files was not loaded in the app.**

So I changed this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

To this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

**And it loaded all the necessary js files.**

**But then I get this error:**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `friends' for nil:NilClass):
```

Comment: What's in both college_friends and highschool_friends partials ? You should have _college_friends.format.erb and _highscool_friends.format.erb in the same folder for this to work

Comment: @anthonyalberto, I get this error If I do as use say: Template is missing

Comment: _college_friends.format.erb => did you replace .format with the actual format? In this example it should be .js.erb I guess !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `friends' for nil:NilClass):
```

Because

```
<% groups = @user.friends.group_by(&:college_name) %>
```

requires `@user` to be set.

As Brandon suggested, try

```
def college_friends
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**BUT**

To achieve this, you need to change your link routes to include user id, similar to this

```
match "college_friends/:id" => "users#college_friends", :as => "college_friends"
```

and in your links

```
<li><%= link_to "College friends", college_friends_path(@user), :remote => true %></li>
```

Comment: thanks! It work, but it makes a new req to the database every time it changes the tabs.. and that is very inefficient. Do you any other idea on how I can rethink this. I am still going to give you the answer.

Comment: Glad if it did help. It think you can ask a new question or search a little for your new problem. But i suggest you to render everything in one request and "show / hide" relevant part of your page as user clicks the links. Now you wont send a new request to server, instead, you will just trigger some js hiding or showing friend tabs. But this time you 'may' not have up-to-date data. That is another problem too :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments above, you should have two partials named `_college_friends.html.erb` and `_highschool_friends.html.erb`

These will contain your HTML, which is what you're wanting to load via `$('#profile-data').html()`

**Template Error:**

You are not defining `@user` in `college_friends` and `highschool_friends`. So your view is requesting `@user` from that action, which isn't there.

Comment: Of course I have to partials that are named liket that! That not the problem

Comment: Which view directory are they saved in? "Template Missing" says you don't have a partial to load. Could you paste the entire error message? I suspect it is looking in views/users/<partial name>

Comment: I fix the template error. All I get right now is a blank page..it send the page to localhost/users/college_friends

Comment: Can you post your partial code? Also, check the http requests in your browser to make sure something is being returned when the link is clicked.

Comment: check the update. what do you mean with something is beging returned?

Comment: It look like the jquery and js files wasint loaded.. but I fix it now. Now when I click the link nothing happens.. And if I look at the source code I cant find college_friends.js.erb. It hasent been loaded in.

Comment: What I mean by "something is being returned" is that when there is an ajax request from the button being clicked, most browsers will capture those requests for you in order to debug. 

Firebug is an option for Firefox: http://getfirebug.com/network/

Internet Explorer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx

Google Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

With this you will see the GET request and result returned. Inspect the result and make sure it is what you're expecting.

Comment: You are not defining `@user` in `college_friends` and `highschool_friends`. So your view is requesting `@user` from that action, which isn't there.

Comment: thank you brandon for your help. I hope to see more of you in stackoverflow! cheers!